# A disabled Input submit button color shouldn't change when the mouse is on it

Tags: asp.net, button, html, razor

I have 2 buttons on a page and enable/disable of these buttons are done by evaluating a checkbox selection.

Currently the disabled button also changing the color when mouse is on them.

I want to control the .css button hover based on whether a button is disabled or enabled.

Do you know how to ensure that the colors shouldn’t change for disabled button when the mouse is on them?

.cshtml

```
<input class="submit-btn submit-right-margin" id="case-escalate" type="submit" value="Update & Escalate" data-caseId="@Model.CaseId"/>

<input class="submit-btn submit-right-margin" id="case-update" type="submit" value="Update" data-caseId="@Model.CaseId"/>
```

.css

```
.submit-btn:hover
{
  color: #2474AD;
  background: #BFDDFF;
}
```

.js
I manage (enable/disable) input submit buttons based on a checkbox selection from a .js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to format disabled inputs:

```
input[disabled] {
    background:gray;
    color:silver;
    ...
}
```

and with `input[disabled]:hover` you can format the hover state.

But the [disabled] is still not working on a few browsers.

**EDIT:**

Never tested this before:
Maybe you can handle this with classes. Just add/remove a class when disabled/enabled with JavaScript.